# What am I doing wrong to access this variable from another class?

Tags: kotlin, plugins, jvm, minecraft, bukkit

Hey so I'm working on a Minecraft Paper plugin in Kotlin, I have a CommandExecutor class named 'SC' with this relevant content:

```
class SC : CommandExecutor {
    companion object {
        private val instance: SC by lazy { SC() }

        fun getSC(): StaffChat {
            return instance.sc
        }
    }
    
    var sc = StaffChat()
```

My toggle system works, but the issue is the Listener class "ChatMsg" which runs on every chat message sent and contains this relevant code:

```
val sc = SC.getSC()
        if (p.hasPermission("void.staff") && sc.getState(p)) {
            sc.sendMsg(p, msgString)
            e.isCancelled = true
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I toggle my staff chat, sending a message doesn't run the correct code to send it to all online staff and instead just sends as a regular message, making me think that the issue is with the 'sc' variable in the Listener class.

What am I doing wrong to access the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "toggle"? Your question doesn't really explain anything about switching implementations.

Comment: Well I have another class 'StaffChat' which stores a hashmap of players and whether or not they currently have staff chat enabled. I create an instance of this 'StaffChat' class in 'SC' and I'm trying to access that same instance from 'ChatMsg'. I'm effectively trying to create a system that allows players to toggle between typing in normal chat and typing in staff chat.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have posted, although that is a convoluted way to create a singleton. Your description of what you're doing with swapping between StaffChat instances sounds like something where you could have a logic problem that would create the behavior you described, but we'd have to see the code that does all that stuff to be sure.

Comment: Here is the [Event Listener](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/443b7debe54440929888183ffc858f04), the [SC Command](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/a1abffa0f17b45ec83f60a80281a65e8), and the [StaffChat Util Class](https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/c7aae4cdf9b148bc8b8a5887def91241).

Comment: I haven't done anything on Minecraft, but if there is some way to log something to the screen or pop up a message, the first thing I would try is putting a log message inside that `if` statement to rule out whether or not your assumption is correct. You can also make your `private var sc` into a `private val sc` to ensure you haven't accidentally swapped the instance somewhere.

Comment: You have two conditions in that if statement. Maybe it's the `void.staff` permission that's missing for whatever reason, and leading you to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: One more idea. Your SC class looks like it's supposed to be a singleton, because you have that instance of it inside its companion object, but its constructor is public, so there exists the possibility of you making more than one instance of it accidentally that could cause some confusion. You should make its constructor private. To do that, change the first line of the class to `class SC private constructor(): CommandExecutor {`